# Can Soomla directories be safely moved one directory down in Unity?

Tags: unity, architecture, asset-management, in-app-purchase, soomla

I'm integrating in-app purchases in my game. To do so, I chose to use Soomla ([http:soom.la](http://soom.la)) asset. I use the free version registering for the `grow` bundle. I've downloaded a `unitypackage` named `unity3d-grow-spend` from my `grow` web console.

When I'm going to import the `unitypackage` I find that it wants to import things in a variety of top-level directories, like:

```
/GROW/*
/Plugins/Android/*
/Plugins/GROW/*
/Plugins/iOS/*
/Plugins/Soomla/*
/Plugins/WP8/*
/Soomla/*
/WebPlayerTemplates/SoomlaConfig/*
```

All this installs inside my `/Assets` directory.

The thing is that in my assets I only have

```
/Assets/Scenes
/Assets/Plugins
```

and I do not want pollution in there.

**Question:**

Is it safe to move `/Assets/GROW` into `/Assets/Vendor/GROW` and move `Soomla` and `WebPlayerTemplates` also into the `Vendor` directory?

Or doing that movement some in-app purchases mechanism will fail?

This would result in having only

```
/Assets/Scenes
/Assets/Plugins
/Assets/Vendor
```

in the top-level, which is rather nice.

Answer (score 1):

Yea, you can safely replace folders and keeping in mind about the [Special Folders Name](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpecialFolders.html). Other than that you can play around with.

Comment: As I use the free version, which is a bundle to `grow`, I moved both, the `/GROW/*` and the `/Soomla/*` into `/Vendor/GROW/*` and `/Vendor/Soomla/*`. Doing so, gives some erros into the log window. Instead, I could still compile and publish, and publication works properly connecting to the play-store in-app purchase market performing the operations from inside `Vendor`. Thanks @Hamza. I'll report more if I ever find why those errors or how to correct them.

Comment: Well... In fact... there is a problem with this move... then it works in the build but stops to work in the editor... Seem no move possible at this moment.

Comment: Can you paste that error?

Comment: Sure, here it is: http://pastebin.com/AE7p9uPL - First, the 3 errors I can see that relate to Soomla. Then, the stack-traces for each of 3.

Comment: Man it is trying to use same path that came with it by default, means Assets/GROW and so on. I didn't use Soomla, so what I can say is to find that editor script, from which this error come from and change its path to Vendor/GROW...

Comment: I already knew you "usually" may move things around up and down. This is why in the title I specified "Soomla", as I wanted to know "for this exact library" if they comply with the standards or not. So I undestand you asserted the answer in a generic way, not specifically to this question, even without having tried with this "Soomla" thing. Will have to wait for people knowing this.Editing the originals is not the way, as then each update of the library shall be a mess.

Comment: May be you are right, then library using a specific path, doesn't supposed to be replaced to another path... As you said, what If another update get that path again.. So ideally you should not change the path of these types of assets